# SmtpException: Syntax error, command unrecognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp-classic, asp.net-core-2.0

This sends an email...

```
Sub SendEmailV2(cdoMessage)

    Dim iConf, Flds

    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    Set Flds = iConf.Fields

    Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2

    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic 
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "MyUsername"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "MyPasswors"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Update
    End With

    cdoMessage.Configuration = iConf
    cdoMessage.Send

End Sub
```

This doesn't...

```
public async Task Send(Message message)
        {
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Host = config.Host; // same host
                smtp.Port = config.Port; // same port
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password); // same username and password
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                var msg = new MailMessage
                {
                    Body = message.Body,
                    Subject = message.Subject,
                    From = new MailAddress(config.FromAddress)
                };

                msg.To.Add(message.To);

                await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
            }
        }
```

Why would the same details not work? It stalls at `ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult`.

Should I create a crude web api and send email from .net using ASP classic?

Comment: You're comparing chalk and cheese, Classic ASP uses CDO, whereas .Net uses it's own SMTP Client framework. One is running synchronously while the other is attempting to send asynchronously. The .Net method likely stalls due to the `SendMailAsync()` call. Just because the same details are piped in doesn't mean both methods will work the same way. Different Tech, different methods.

Comment: They might not work the same way, but surely they should both work. What’s wrong with an async call?

Comment: They probably should both work, but basing your question on the fact that the Classic ASP CDO method works but the .Net Async method doesn't is pointless. Focus your question around asking why the Async call in .Net is failing. Have you tried using `Send()` instead to take async out of the equation?

Comment: Yes. Its says, "IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this...

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

I've seen a few posts about .net's SmtpClient not working well when TLS is required.

```
   public async Task Send(Message message)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(config.FromName, config.FromAddress));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(message.To));
        emailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = message.Body };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(config.Host, config.Port, true);

            await client.AuthenticateAsync(config.Username, config.Password);

            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);

            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
    }
```